Git: Merge all files except specified ones
I have two git repositories, let's call them WidgetsParent and WidgetsChild for the purposes of this.
WidgetsParent moves a lot quicker than WidgetsChild and, on a periodic basis, WidgetsChild needs to stay up to date with it.
WidgetsChild however, has it's own custom changes, some folders are removed, other files are being changed to add custom configuration.
Now, I've added WidgetsParent as a git remote of WidgetsChild and I've added some of the files / folders to .gitignore that I don't want to merge.
Just wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this or some git command I haven't considered to keep the two in sync, but ensure the custom files or changed files don't have horrific merge conflicts every time I try to git merge? Perhaps git-filter-repo could help here?
For example, as these are NodeJS repositories, the package.json is almost identical except one or two dependencies may change, or the npm scripts may change from time to time.

Do you mean that WidgetPrent has two remotes? If so, do you want to push specific files to a specific remote?

No I mean that WidgetChild specifies a remote of WidgetParent to keep it in sync

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories

I think we need a new tag git-branches-as-configuration-management. Then we can answer one of them as “don’t do it” and redirect the other questions to that one.
